# Equation to take out a percentage from a number and have the leftover.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Someone argued with me about the right way to deduct a percentage from a number and have the leftover. Say for example 20% of 2000.

Their way: 2000/1.20 = 1,666 (but that seems wrong???)

My way: 2000-(.20*2000) = $1600

What's the best fool-proof equation for this?

Comment: What's wrong with $2000 \times .8$ ?

Comment: Yours is correct if it is required to subtract 20% of 2000 from 2000.
2000/1.20 seems to be finding a number whose 120% is 2000.

Comment: You can explain those people that "subtracting $20\%$ to x" is *not* the inverse of "adding $20\%$ to x", if you happen to meet them again.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to decrease $2000$ by $20\,\%$, your way is right, resulting in $1600$.

If you are given that $2000$ was obtained by adding $20\,\%$ to an unknown amount and want to computer that amount, their way is right. Indeed, if you add $20\,\%$ (using your method) to $1666.66$ you get (approximately) $2000$.